# Moving a sprite (SpriteKit) along a UIBezierPath in steps

Tags: sprite-kit, uibezierpath

I am able to generate a UIBezierPath as well as use SKAction.followPath in order to make a sprite follow this path after calling runAction.  With this, I can make the sprite follow a bezier path from the start of the path to the endpoint.

However, what I'm actually going for is the following:

1. Generate a fixed path, such as with UIBezierPath
2. This path will have about 10 points along it
3. Using a button press, I will move the sprite (currently on the starting point along this path) one "move" along to the next point.
4. Using button presses, I'll continuously move the sprite along that fixed path in those 10 discrete steps

Probably the most similar example to what I'm trying to achieve is with the Candy Crush level map.  In this, you have some curvy path along which there are points that you move your character along in discrete steps.

Thank you for any help!

[image: World Map]

Answer (score 1):

instead of using a bezier path why not store the points in an array.  Then each time you touch the button just pop off the end of the array and do `SKAction.moveTo(yourPoint)`